# Why is the variance of a binomial distribution different from that calculated with sum of squared differences divided by n?

Tags: variance, binomial-distribution

For n= 5, p = 0.5

If I calculate the variance using np(1-p) I get 1.25

If I calculate using the sum of the squared differences divided by n
As explained [here](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/statistics/variance-calculator.php)
I get 3.5

What am I missing?

[image: excel picture]

Comment: You need to multiply the difference by the probabilities not by the number of values $X$ can take.

Comment: $\frac{17.5}{15}\neq 3.5$. And $\frac{17.5}{14}=1.25$

Comment: Why would you divide by $n$?  With sampled data, the $\frac 1n$ or $\frac 1{n-1}$ arises from counting measure. We have no reason to assign a greater probability to one event or another.  Here, we have the probabilities of each case so compute the weighted sum of the squared differences.

Comment: @Patricio n is 5 why are you dividing by 15?

Comment: @lulu "Compute the weighted sum of the squared differences." That is the answer. When I multiplied column F by column C it all made sense.

Comment: @KirstenGreed, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The formula for the variance is

$$Var(X)=\sum_{k=0}^5 (x_k-\mu)^2\cdot f_X(k),$$

where $f_X(k)$ is the pmf of the binomial distribution which can be interpreted as a weight. See the table.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. PMF instead of PDF?

Comment: Yeah, pmf is the right word.

Comment: As given by the 2nd column

Comment: @KirstenGreed Yes, the 2nd column contains the values of the pmf.